# Uso de la estructura "Tener + participio"

Tags: gramática

En esta página web en inglés https://baselang.com/blog/vocabulary/spanish-grammar-how-to-stop-confusing-tener-vs-haber/ encontré en el punto 4 una explanación de esta estructura tener + participio:

"The verb tener is sometimes used as an auxiliary verb in order to reiterate or emphasize an executed action in the sentence....In the auxiliary form, tener expresses an action that has not completely ended, or has a continuation until something interrupts it....

***Tengo entendido** que ese camino está cerrado* - If we break it down, then “*tengo entendido*” means that someone explained something to me at some point and that information is still valid for me, since I have not received any information that says the opposite.

“*He entendido*” refers to something recent, what someone just explained to me, and I just understand it."

Pero debido a que esto está explicado por non-nativo, no estoy completamente seguro de que sea correcta esta explicación.

Preguntas:

1. ¿Es correcto lo que expliqué el autor?
2. ¿Por si es correcto, aun así no entiendo cómo usar esta estructura, en cuáles circunstancias? Tengo una impresión de que esta estructura se usa muy raro.
3. Tengo unos ejemplos los que encontré y que posiblemente caben en la explicación del autor (la que en inglés). ¿O no? Los siguientes:

De la película "Contratiempo" (España):

"*La policía ha convertido esto en una celda, me **tienen vigilado** las 24 horas del día.*"

Del libro "El arte de no amargarse la vida" (España):

"-¿*Ni siquiera teme a la muerte, estando amenazado?*

-*A mí me **la tienen jurada** varias mafias de tráfico de niños porque les quito la materia prima de su comercio*."

P.S. Por adelantado les agradezco a todos ustedes los que corrijan errores en mi letra si haya algunos, o en gramática o en uso de palabras o en algo más.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La explicación dada por el sitio web es bastante genérica. Probablemente te sirvan más algunos ejemplos, ya que esta estructura no siempre significa lo mismo.

Hay una relación clara entre “tener” + participio y el tiempo verbal compuesto equivalente (que usa el auxiliar “haber”). Esta relación proviene de que “haber” originalmente significaba “tener”. (De hecho, en portugués se utiliza el verbo “ter”, equivalente al español “tener”, como auxiliar en los tiempos compuestos). El significado de “tener” + participio no es igual, pero **incluye** al del tiempo compuesto.

“Tengo entendido que...” implica “He entendido que...”, pero no hace referencia directa al pasado ni a ninguna continuidad de la acción. Si yo digo “He entendido”, estoy implicando que en algún momento del pasado no entendía y luego eso cambió; pero si digo “Tengo entendido”, simplemente estoy describiendo mi estado actual: estoy en posesión del entendimiento. No obstante, “tengo entendido” implica indirectamente que en algún momento conseguí entender algo.

“Me tienen vigilado” significa aproximadamente lo mismo que “Me están vigilando”, “Estoy siendo vigilado”. Es una condición actual, no algo del pasado, pero (de nuevo) hay una implicación indirecta de que en algún momento alguien comenzó a vigilarme (y sigue haciéndolo).

“Me la tienen jurada” es una frase hecha, pero funciona bajo el mismo principio que las otras. “La” (la cosa que “me tienen jurada”) es la venganza, la muerte, el castigo, etc. No hace falta decir qué es (como cuando decimos “La pasé muy bien”). “Tienen jurado (algo)” significa “Han jurado (algo) y el juramento sigue vigente”. “Me la tienen jurada”, entonces, significa “Han jurado (la muerte) para mí; existe y está vigente actualmente un juramento para causarme (la muerte)”. Te aconsejaría que no te preocupes mucho por esta frase porque, como te dije, es una expresión hecha.

Puedo darte otros ejemplos más comunes. Por ejemplo, imaginemos una madre (M) y un hijo (H) en edad escolar.

> M: —¿Ya has hecho la tarea?
> H: —Sí, la tengo hecha desde ayer.
> M: —¿Y el libro que tenías que leer?
> H: —Ya lo tengo leído y estudiado.

El hijo podría haber respondido ambas preguntas usando el pretérito compuesto o el pretérito simple (esto es preferencia dialectal), pero prefiere usar el “tener” + participio porque no quiere expresar cuándo terminó la acción, sino enfatizar que el resultado de la acción es su estado actual (y, en el caso de la tarea, desde cuándo es así).

Observa que cuando usas “tener” + participio, el participio concuerda en género y número con el objeto, a diferencia de lo que ocurre con los tiempos compuestos (donde el participio es invariable).